# Can I review and delete Celery / RabbitMQ tasks individually?

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I am running Django + Celery + RabbitMQ. After modifying some task names I started getting "unregistered task" KeyErrors, even after removing tasks with this key from the Periodic tasks table in Django Celery Beat and restarting the Celery worker.

It turns out [Celery / RabbitMQ tasks are persistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739336/can-celery-tasks-survive-restart). I eventually resolved the issue by [reimplementing the legacy tasks as dummy methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45920778).

In future, I'd prefer not to purge the queue, restart the worker or reimplement legacy methods. Instead I'd like to inspect the queue and individually delete any legacy tasks. Is this possible? (Preferably in the context of the Django admin interface.)

Comment: related but doesn't address deleting tasks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049829/how-can-i-view-the-enqueued-tasks-in-rabbitmq

Comment: reference http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html

Comment: flower plugin would be helpful to inspect

Answer (score 0):

Celery `inspect` may help

To view active queues:

```
celery -A proj inspect active_queues
```

To terminate a process:

```
celery -A proj control invoke process_id
```

To see all availble inspect options:

```
celery inspect --help
```